Table of contents in a Drupal site not returning content
I have a Drupal 10 (v10.1.x-dev) site that uses the toc_js (v2.1.0) contrib module. The table of contents is toggled on/off from within the admin toolbar and the container is rendering on the page but none of the headers  -  load.
Here is an image of what it looks like:

Tried reinstalling with different versions and manually changing code where appropriate to debug and fix.

what error are you getting check console and let us know
